# Android Coroutine: Revert all the job if anyone job failed

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

Suppose

Job1 -> do the first API call

Job2 -> save the data in the database(ROOM)

Job3 -> do the second API call

Job4 -> save the data in the database(ROOM)

Job5 -> process the data(or some other task)

suppose Job3 failed(because of exception, invalid response, the user manually cancelled, app closed...) then revert Job2 and Job1 also

currently, I am using:

```
val mainJob = CoroutineScope(IO).launch{
val result1 = async{}.await()//API call Say:Job1
val result2 = async{}.await()// Save data in database Say:Job2
val result3 = async{result1//uses result1 in this job to do API call}.await()//API call Say:Job3
val result4 = async{}.await()// Save data in database Say:Job4
val result5 = async{}.await()// some task Say:Job5
}
```

the problem in this approach is if cancelling mainJob at result3 or result4 is not reverting the data stored in the database at the time of execution of Job2.

Please don't give answer, like hold job2 data in the app memory in some variable and store it in the database only when all the job run successfully.

I must need to store the data in the database in job2.

Comment: revert to some version or overwrite it? if you would like to overwrite you can clear db at all, on the other case for ex you can store prev version before all jobs for restoring it due to the failure

Comment: Your entire usage pattern is wrong for Kotlin coroutines. Writing `async { stuff() }.await()` is just as good as writing `stuff()` directly. Also, `CoroutineScope(IO).launch { }` is just a superficial way of writing `GlobalScope.launch(IO) { }` without triggering the helpful warning that `GlobalScope` is sensitive API and there's a good chance you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: As for your direct question about non-transactional behavior, you should properly demarcate the entire code block as belonging to a single database transaction. Database transactions work the same way whether used from coroutines or not.